# Is there a way to run a block of code of my application, when it is in the background? (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift

Let's say I would like to recreate the functionality of the default Clock app and its timer. When I set a timer, leave the application and proceed to do something else on my iPhone I get a    UIAlertView displayed even though I am not currently in the Clock app, which means, that the code must have somehow ran in the background. How can I do that in my app?